# Console tests halt without error

Tags: scala, scalatest

When running SBT `test` from the terminal, after a while tests hang without throwing an error.

1. How do you allocate more memory to the test runner?(if needed)
2. Is there a log file anywhere? Can't find anything in the docs.
3. The Eclipse integration of ScalaTest is rubish, are there better alternatives?

`last:test` is useless since no error is actually thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test is hanging up, then my first suspicion is that you may have an infinite tail recursion somewhere.  I doubt that (1) will help you since typically you will get an `OutOfMemoryError` or some other error if you don't have enough.  (2) The only logging I'm aware of is printed to the console.  (3) You're already doing the right thing by using the console.

Disable parallel execution of your tests to allow you to determine which test is getting stuck and if it is consistently the same test, then go from there.  Add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```